# Python - pandas_datareader Error: "data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Tags: python, python-3.9, pandas-datareader

I really can't seem to figure out this error that I keep getting from the simple code below. I am using `Python 3.9.13` and `pandas 2.1.2` . I appreciate in advance the help in figuring this out.

```
import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

start = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 8)

df = web.DataReader('BTC-USD', 'yahoo', start='2022-01-01', end='2022-06-14')
df.tail(5)
```

The error message I get from the above piece of code is:

```
"data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]TypeError: string indices must be integers"
```

As a workaround, I have tried the following method, which worked. However, this is not an efficient method as I had to manually save the data file in my project repository.

```
df = pd.read_excel('../data/input/subSet.xlsx')
df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo changed their finance API and i don't think the pandas-datareader crew does anything about it. See discussion here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/952

Its suggested to work with different packages. yfinance seems to work fine and is also using the Yahoo finance API (https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/).Here is a solution that could work:

```
import yfinance as yf
import datetime

# Define the ticker symbol and date range
ticker = "BTC-USD"
start = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=365)
end = datetime.datetime.now()

# Download the historical stock prices
data = yf.download(ticker, start=start, end=end)

# Print the data
print(data)
```